# Scaling issues when exporting FBX models from CityEngine

Tags: export, scale, cityengine

I have extruded a dataset of circles into cylinders based on values in an attribute table using CityEngine and I am trying to export this into an FBX model for use in 3DS Max as well as Infraworks 360. The model is correct in CityEngine, however when I export the model the units and therefore scale are well off. The units of the model in CityEngine are in metres as it is set in the British National Grid Co-ordinate system, but when the FBX model is brought into 3DS Max it is being read as centimetres and converting it to metres then throws off the co-ordinates by factor of 100 so it is not properly geo-located.

I have read some forums online which suggest that CityEngine can only export in centimetres, does anyone know if this is true?

I have attached screenshots of the model in CityEngine, export settings for the FBX model and the scale issues in 3DS Max. 
[image: CityEngine Model][image: FBX Export Settings][image: FBX Import Settings 3DS Max][image: Scale Issue 3DS Max]

Answer (score 1):

Yes. There is a limitation in CityEngine that it doesn't properly write the unit information for FBX files.

The only solution I can propose to you is the following:

1. Use the center functionality on export.
2. Read of the offsets the center point has in the X/Y/Z-Offset fields.
3. Actually export the file.
4. Scale it properly in 3DS Max.
5. Use the offset you noted before and translate your model in 3DS Max accordingly.
6. You should now have the model correctly scaled and accurately placed.